# Animation to scale and move UIView (swift)

Tags: swift, animation, uiview

I have a UIView, placed in the middle of the screen. When the user presses a button, I want it to move up near top of the screen as it shrinks to about a fifth of its size.

I have tried this:

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.7) { () -> Void in
            self.main.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.2, 0.2)
            self.main.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, -250)
        }
```

But for some reason, that only scales the view. I have also tried to put this in the animateWithDuration:

```
self.main.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.width/2 - 10, 50, 50, 50)
```

How can I get both animations to work?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Joe's answer above does exactly as his GIF describes but it doesn't really answer your question since it translates *then* scales the view (as opposed to both translating and scaling at the same time). Your issue is that you're setting the view's transform in your animation block then immediately overwritting that value with another transform. To achieve both translation and scale at the same time, you'll want something like this:

```
@IBAction func animateButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let originalTransform = self.main.transform
    let scaledTransform = originalTransform.scaledBy(x: 0.2, y: 0.2)
    let scaledAndTranslatedTransform = scaledTransform.translatedBy(x: 0.0, y: -250.0)
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.7, animations: {
        self.main.transform = scaledAndTranslatedTransform
    })
}
```

Comment: thanks for the solution. But the translation move my view on a relatively. How can i move it to fix screenco-ordinate like x=100 y=100 position ???. I realize that the translated move your position relative to current position.

Comment: @Md.Sulayman You'll need to calculate the difference between your destination x and y coordinates and the coordinates of your UIView then translate your UIView by that amount. If you'd like to see a code example, feel free to open up another question and link me here :)

Answer (score 43):

You can achieve basic `UIView animation` in several ways in **Swift**. Below code is just a simple approach...

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var animationButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var myView: UIView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // I added seperate colour to UIView when animation move from one animation block to another.So, You can get better understanding how the sequence of animation works.
  self.myView.backgroundColor = .red
}

@IBAction func animateButton(_ sender: UIButton) {

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0.0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.curveEaseIn, animations: { 
        //Frame Option 1:
        self.myView.frame = CGRect(x: self.myView.frame.origin.x, y: 20, width: self.myView.frame.width, height: self.myView.frame.height)

        //Frame Option 2:
        //self.myView.center = CGPoint(x: self.view.frame.width / 2, y: self.view.frame.height / 4)
        self.myView.backgroundColor = .blue

        },completion: { finish in

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, delay: 0.25,options: UIViewAnimationOptions.curveEaseOut,animations: {
        self.myView.backgroundColor = .orange      
        self.myView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.25, y: 0.25)

        self.animationButton.isEnabled = false // If you want to restrict the button not to repeat animation..You can enable by setting into true

        },completion: nil)})

      }
     }
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: hello. i have done this but mu uiimageview is shrinked after making this animation

Comment: @Md.Sulayman thats the whole idea of the post shrink the view after animation. Read the post again. And let me know what you trying to achieve?

Comment: but my image aspect ratio is lost after animation, shrink is not problem, i wanted that too

Comment: @Md.Sulayman that might be a different issue...check your constraints?

Comment: My scenario is i disabled all constarint before animation, added a scale and translation at the same time. Actually i needed both at the same time 
" let originalTransform = self.idImageView.transform
  let scaledTransform = originalTransform.scaledBy(x: widthOfIDImage/displayWidth, y: heightOfIDImage/displayHeight)
  let scaledAndTranslatedTransform = scaledTransform.translatedBy(x: 200, y: -1000)
  self.idImageView.transform = scaledAndTranslatedTransform

Comment: i just figured out the problem . i gave different scaling value for x and y, that cause the aspect ratio problem

Comment: I think there may be a problem with your brackets in the code