# Why is UILabel TextColor animated in a Playground, but not on a device?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, animation, swift-playground

So I want to animate a change in text color for some UILabels. I've had mixed success.

One of the things I eventually got to was trying it out in a Swift Playground using Xcode 8. In it's simplest form the code to run the animation is:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 5.0) {
    label.textColor = UIColor.red
    label.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 2, y: 2)
}
```

However, when I plug that same code into an empty (Swift) iOS project, the text color is no longer animated.

I understand that UILabel textColor property is not supposed to be animatable, yet here it is animating. Any clues as to what's going on? Perhaps something to do with the PlaygroundSupport module?

Here is the animation as viewed in the Playground:

[image: Playground Animation]

Here is the animation as drawn in the Simulator:

[image: Simulator Animation]

EDIT: Added animations to clarify what's going on a little better

Comment: Set your label background colour  to green and run the project.see you can able to see your label and make sure your label have some text to show then copy and paste your code into viewDidLoad or inside your button action and run the project again...this should work....

Comment: If you still trouble finding a answer.can you post your storyBoard hierarchy...problem could be from your IBOutlet

Comment: @Joe I don't have any trouble _seeing_ the UILabel, or even modifying it. The issue is that it won't animate. It will only change instantly, despite the animation supposed to last 5 seconds. If I add a position change/apply a transformation, that animates just fine over the specified time period. It's only the textColor animation portion that is causing all the grief. I don't understand why it works in a Playground, yet not in a project. I'm pretty concerned/confused as to why it works for you, too.

Comment: R u trying from the simulator or real device..but 5 sec is easy enough to see the animation or apply some animation startup delay to it...

Comment: check my update....

Comment: @Joe Thanks. I've removed a little more ambiguity from my question with some images. I see you have the same issue with the textColor not actually animating the color change.

Comment: Code updated..........

Comment: Look at my answer on this post.may you get better understanding how the animation perform accordingly with colour assigned http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40318081/animation-to-scale-and-move-uiview-swift/40318316#40318316

Comment: let me know. if you still having issue....

Answer (score 0):

**Updated Answer:**

**Note:** Just, copy and paste below code into your viewController and connect your IBOutlets and run the project.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@IBOutlet weak var animateLabel: UILabel!

@IBAction func animateButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
      // textColor will change from blue to red...
      animateLabel.textColor = .blue // set any colour 
      UIView.animate(withDuration: 5.0) {
       self.animateLabel.textColor = UIColor.red
        self.animateLabel.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 2, y: 2)
    }
  }
}
```

Output:

[image]

Your code looks ok.Set your textColor to different colour rather than white.As you mentioned. you running this code on empty project that means default viewController background also in white colour thats why you can't see the animation.Hope below code helps.

```
 label.textColor = UIColor.red // set to any colour
```

**Note:** If you want keep your textColor as white..change the text colour background or apply some shadow to your label t make it visible.

```
//apply backgroundcolor to your label
label.backgroundColor = UIColor.green // set to any colour

// apply shadow to your label
self.label.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
self.label.layer.shadowOpacity = 1
self.label.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize.zero
self.label.layer.shadowRadius = 10
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. Unfortunately, the issue wasn't about the text hiding in the background, I guess that was a bit ambiguous in using UIColor.white. I've updated it now (I had a different background color). Any idea on why the code works in the Playground environment, and not the _actual_ iOS environment?

Comment: I already tested your code before I posted my answer.did you put your code inside your viewDidLoad or outside? If your code inside your viewDidLoad it should works.let me know...

Comment: Nope, it doesn't work :( Have had it as part of the view lifecycle, and also attached to a button. Tried with a label in a storyboard, and programmatically creating a label. Works just fine in the Playground, not in an iOS project. I could post more code, but the only other code is boilerplate.